# Overriding multiple interface methods in Kotlin lambda expressions

Tags: android, lambda, interface, kotlin

Say I have a `Callbacks` interface with two methods `onCurrentLocation` and `onError`:

```
    public interface Callbacks {

        void onCurrentLocation(ClientLocation location);

        void onError();
    }
```

and a class that takes this interface in its constructor, say:

```
public MyLocationClient(Callbacks callbacks) {...}
```

Now, in Kotlin, should I be able to instantiate MyLocationClient this way:

```
val myLocationClient = MyLocationClient(
                    { location: ClientLocation ->
                          updateClientLocation(location)
                    },
                    {})
```

and if not, why not?

The behavior I'm seeing is: When the interface only has one method, the construction of this object compiles fine. But, as soon as I add more methods to `Callbacks`, the compiler complains

> "Type mismatch.  Required: Callbacks!  Found: (ClientLocation) ->
>   Unit"

Edit: removed the null check for `location` since it was irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a good thing, that it doesn't work, because what do you do, when the interface has two functions of the same type?

```
public interface Callbacks {
    void anotherFunction(ClientLocation location);

    void onCurrentLocation(ClientLocation location);
}
```

So restricting this to SAM (single abstract method) interfaces is a good approach I would say.

Comment: I'm thinking of making this the accepted answer because, to my understanding, this is in fact the reason why you can't do what I'm asking.

Answer (score 6):

So you're creating an instance on an anonymous class that is not a functional interface (they only have one method) so it would be something like :

```
val myLocationClient = MyLocationClient(object : Callbacks {

        override fun onCurrentLocation(location : ClientLocation?){
            location?.run{ updateLocation(this) }
        }

        override fun onError(){ // should you not handle errors? }
    })
```

Comment: Yes, this code works fine, but I'm trying to avoid the "boilerplate" code using kotlin lambdas. In fact, that's the gist of my question.

Comment: I explained why, you don't have a functional interface, that is how it is written in Kotlin - having `,` between method implementations in the same anonymous class isn't valid in Kotlin. If you want to create less boiler plate split it out into 2 functional interfaces and have the constructor take 2 arguments then you're implementation would work or just remove `onError()` in your interface since you have any implementation for it anyway

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't look up what a functional interface is. Is this in the Kotlin docs anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can define

```
class CallbacksImpl(private val onCurrentLocationF: (ClientLocation) -> Unit, private val onErrorF: () -> Unit) : Callbacks {
  override fun onCurrentLocation(location : ClientLocation) { onCurrentLocationF(location) }

  override fun onError() { onErrorF() }
}
```

and use it

```
MyLocationClient(CallbacksImpl(
    { location -> updateClientLocation(location) },
    {}))
```

It still has some boilerplate, but once per interface instead of once per use, so it can easily be a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IAnimatedRatingBar {
   fun setProgressImageResource(resourceId: Int)


   fun setProgressImageDrawable(drawable: Drawable)


   fun setSecondaryProgressImageResource(resourceId: Int)


   fun setSecondaryProgressImageDrawable(drawable: Drawable)

   fun startAnimate()
}
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Can you include the syntax you used to pass this as a function argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can use higher order function of Kotlin and merge both method of interface check this example

```
import android.location.Location

interface Callbacks {

 fun onCurrentLocation(location: Location)
 
 fun onError()

}
```

Now define a class that implement Callbacks interface

```
import android.location.Location

class MyLocationClient(private val callbackListener: (isSuccess:Boolean, location: Location?, error:String) -> Unit): Callbacks {

override fun onCurrentLocation(location: Location) {
    callbackListener(true,location, "No Error")
}

override fun onError() {
    callbackListener(false,null, "Unable to get location")
}

}
```

Use it wherever you like

```
val myLocationClient = MyLocationClient { isSuccess, location, error ->
        if (isSuccess){
            // proceed with location
        }else{
            // error occured show it to user
        }
    }
```